# PHPSpreadSheet | Saving XLSX unhides every row

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

```
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$fileName");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
$writer->save('php://output');
```

All of the rows get un-hidden when exporting like that. I've verified that the rows are in fact hidden in the original file.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you make literaly a copy you must hide the row before you write the document. To hide line 10 use:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('10')->setVisible(false);
```

More information arivable in the documentation [here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#showhide-a-row)

Comment: The file already has hidden rows. How can I keep those same rows hidden if I don't know their indexes when exporting?

Comment: You can ask iterate over the lines and check the height of the line if it is 0 it should be hidden.